# Can't get link_to to work on nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

There seem to be a few questions like this but I have read all of them but they don't help.

I have this in `views/towns/index.html.haml`:

```
= link_to "towns attractions", towns_attractions(town.id)
```

I have done an `inspect` on `town.id` and the `id` is correct.

My routes seem okay because I can go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/towns
```

and I can go to

```
http://127.0.0.1:3000/towns/1/attractions
```

when I take my `link_to` out (because it breaks).

However, I get this error in `index.html.haml`:

```
undefined method `towns_attractions'
```

I have tried all combinations of pluralization with no luck!

My routes:

```
resources :towns do
    resources :attractions
end
```

rake routes:

```
 town_attractions GET    /towns/:town_id/attractions(.:format)     attractions#index
                         POST   /towns/:town_id/attractions(.:format)     attractions#create
  new_town_attraction GET    /towns/:town_id/attractions/new(.:format) attractions#new
               towns GET    /towns(.:format)                             towns#index
                         POST   /towns(.:format)                             towns#create
            new_town GET    /towns/new(.:format)                         towns#new
           edit_town GET    /towns/:id/edit(.:format)                    towns#edit
                town GET    /towns/:id(.:format)                         towns#show
                         PUT    /towns/:id(.:format)                         towns#update
                         DELETE /towns/:id(.:format)                         towns#destroy
```

All I want is a link that goes to `http://127.0.0.1:3000/towns/1/attractions` but where `1` is replaced by `town.id`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`towns_attractions` should be `town_attractions_path`. That's it.

Comment: Thank you!  Argh so simple.